# Is there a way to check version of an application installed on a user's machine?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to find a way where I can find the version of a particular software installed on the computer, maybe if there's a Library which can help or something else, but couldn't find anything. Please suggest if you have some solution to this.

Thanks.

Comment: No there isn't. You should describe why you need that and what you want to achieve with that. Based on that information it might be possible to give you another solution.

Comment: Actually there's a software called OCalc which you might've heard about, so based on the version of the software installed certain functionalities might work and certain ones might not.

Comment: Not from inside the browser, that would be a huge security/privacy breach.

Comment: No, I don't know OCalc and a short search does not show me a Software with that name that would extend the functionality of the browser. Anyway, that is still not a helpful description. What could you do if the software is installed with JavaScript/Reactjs and how would it fail if the software is not present?